# Empty rows from the autocomplete list instead of suggested names while typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have a strange problem. I get some info in JSON form from a php file.
I have tested that with console.log and the data does return in JSON form to be passed as potential choices in an autocomplete form. But, the list that comes out, down from the input just contains rows with no data at all. Here's the piece of code I have for the autocomplete feature:

```
$(function() {   
        $( "#searchArea" ).autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 2,           
              source: function(request, response) {
              $.ajax({
              url: 'search.php', 
              data: { term: request.term }, 
              success: function(data) {  
                                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                return {
                                label: item.firstName,
                                value: item.userID};
                                }));
              }
            });
          }
        })
    });
```

I don't get it. Obviously I am missing something in the response call but can't figure out what. The data returned from php contain results, from a SELECT query, in multiple arrays like these:

> {"1":{"userID":"1","firstName":"Mike"},"2":{"userID":"2","firstName":"Michael"}}

Any help - guidance will be appreciated as I have been around this from the morning.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine if response containing data formatted as this

```
{"1":{"userID":"1","firstName":"Mike"},"2":{"userID":"2","firstName":"Michael"}}
```

test the code

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            var data = {"1":{"userID":"1","firstName":"Mike"},"2":{"userID":"2","firstName":"Michael"}}
            $( "#automp" ).autocomplete({
               source: function(request, response) {
                   response( $.map( data, function(item) {
                    // your operation on data
                    return {
                               label: item.firstName,
                               value: item.userID
                           }
                    }));
               }
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div class="ui-widget">
         <p>Type mike</p>
         <label for="automp">Users: </label>
         <input id="automp">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

So you have to check the response coming from server in the ajax success call back.Then if response is coming properly you have to check the response is json formatted or not.you may try this if this is not json formatted

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Well, that way it did actually work! I burned one day just for this only to see that I actually was parsing the data to another variable and still was assigning from the un-parsed data variable. That's a shame :/ Anyway, thank you for your interest and your time spent with my silly problem. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding limit:100 to typeahead with source, I don't know the reason, but setting to 100 I could fix the issue.

```
$('#ahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,highlight: true,
            },
 {
            limit:100,
            source: bloodhound,
....
}
```